# Python3, using object instance within another class

Tags: python, python-3.x, instance-variables

I'm trying to modify class attribute by reference to object in `__init__` method and then use it in another method. Sadly the following code sample doesn't work as expected...

**CODE**

```
class Translator:
    #list of attributes
    parser=None
    def __init__(self):   
         parser = Parser_class() ...
         #some other commands
    def Translate(self): 
         something=self.parser.GenerateHead() ...
         #more commands
```

**COMPILE ERR**

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GenerateHead'
```

I know that I can give it to the `Translate` method as argument, I'm just curious why this statement within Python doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing your instance attributes wrong.

First off, you don't need to declare your attributes ahead of time. Putting `parser = None` at the top level of the class creates a class variable named `parser`, which I don't think is what you want. Usually in Python you can add new instance attributes at any time by a simple assignment: `instance.attr = "whatever"`.

Second, when you want to do an instance assignment from within a method, you need to use `self` to refer to the instance. If you leave off `self`, you'll be assigning to a local variable inside your function, not to an instance or class variable. Actually, the specific name `self` isn't necessary, but you do need to use the first argument to the method (and it's probably not a good idea to break the convention of naming that `self`).

So, to fix your code, do this:

```
class Translator:
    # don't declare variables at class level (unless you actually want class variables)

    def __init__(self):   
         self.parser = Parser_class()   # use self to assign an instance attribute

    def Translate(self): 
         something = self.parser.GenerateHead()  # this should now work
```